# Is that any similar thing like cache for Mobile(cordova)

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I am developing a mobile apps using cordova 3.10 ,HTML5 and jquery mobile , The Apps will be targeting Apple, android, blackberry and windows phone. Currently the apps every time will call back to server and grab data. even though i switch page and back it also will call the page.

I would like to implement a cache for the apps , so that i can reduce the call to my server, but i have no idea where should start from for the caching method.

Any advice will be appreciate .

Comment: you could save the data in the phones localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [HTML5 caching](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp) or (as Daniel says), use local storage - [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) makes this pretty easy with Phonegap.

Comment: lawnchair , save data at where ? phone local storage ?

Comment: Yes, lawnchair uses local storage. It just provides a consistent, clean interface to the various underlying mechanisms that can be used for local storage.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the other two posts, for data, I would just use local storage.

For the app:

**data-dom-cache="true"** (Default is **false**)

http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/

Search that page to see all the widgets you can add that attribute to.

> if you prefer, you can tell jQuery Mobile to keep previously-visited pages in the DOM instead of removing them. This lets you cache pages so that they're available instantly if the user returns to them.
>
> To keep all previously-visited pages in the DOM, set the domCache
>   option on the page plugin to true, like this:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```

> Alternatively, to cache just a particular page, you can add the
>   data-dom-cache="true" attribute to the page's container:

```
<div data-role="page" id="cacheMe" data-dom-cache="true">
```

> You can also cache a page programmatically like this:

```
pageContainerElement.page({ domCache: true });
```

> The drawback of DOM caching is that the DOM can get very large,
>   resulting in slowdowns and memory issues on some devices. If you
>   enable DOM caching, take care to manage the DOM yourself and test
>   thoroughly on a range of devices.